# Click on buster captcha solver icon on captcha image via cypress

Tags: automation, cypress, recaptcha, captcha

I am trying to click on the one icon highlighted in the image. I am getting error here I am getting Assertion Error

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: [title="Solve the challenge"], but never found it.

here is my code

```
cy.get('[style="z-index: 2000000000; position: relative; width: 400px; height: 580px;"] > iframe').then(($iFrameContent) => {
cy.wait(5000)
const $body = $iFrameContent.contents().find('body');

cy.wrap($body).find(' #solver-button').should('be.visible').click();
cy.wait(5000)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using an [iframe cypress plugin](https://gitlab.com/kgroat/cypress-iframe)  instead of `cy.get()` approach?

Comment: I  never tried this with iframe plugin. I saw one course have this solution, Rahul shetty explained this with using frame plugin. I will see that Thanks!